# Hide column with + plus for displaying subgrids in jqgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jqgrid, subgrid

Any idea how I can hide the column with the + icons that displays the subgrid of a jqgrid for asp mvc. I have another column that displays the subgrid and I will like to hide the plus column. Any ideas? Thx.

```
Solution:    
  function OnGridInitialized() {
                 $('#UserSessionGrid').jqGrid('hideCol', 'subgrid');
             }

In c# code: 
 userSessionsGrid.ClientSideEvents.GridInitialized = "OnGridInitialized";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column with "+" sign is in many sense just normal column of jqGrid. It has the column name "subgrid":

```
$('#list').jqGrid('hideCol', 'subgrid');
```

There are three very close cases:

- subgrid column holding '+' or "-" signs has the name "subgrid". It exists if the option `subgrid: true` are used;
- multiselect column with checkboxs has the name "cb". It exists if the option `multiselect: true` are used;
- the column with row numbers has the name "rn". It exists if the option `rownumbers: true` are used.

So one can hide any from the columns with respect of `hideCol`. On the other side the names "subgrid", "cb" and "rn" are reserved names and one can't use the name as the value of the `name` property.

Comment: I've tried both solutions above, adding the call in my document ready function, but none is working. Would themeroller have any effect on this?

Comment: @TunjiAdeloye: No. Could you post the code which you currently use: the code which define the grid with subgrid and where you call `.jqGrid('hideCol', 'subgrid')`

Comment: @TunjiAdeloye: the code `$('#UserSessionGrid').jqGrid('hideCol', 'subgrid');` must be called **after** the grid is created which is not the case in your code. Moreover you use probably commercial version of jqGrid, so you should better use [jqgrid-asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-asp.net/info) tag of your question instead of [jqgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid/info) tag.

Comment: I have made some changes to call the funtion after the grid is created as suggested and it works now. I didn't realize there were differences between jqgrid & jqgrid-asp.net interms of the tags. I will take note for future issues. The fix is posted above. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the jqGrid demo and ran this against it, which you can run inside document ready:

```
$(function(){
  $('td.ui-sgcollapsed').hide()
});
```

hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This didn't hide the column as desired, after adding the call in my document ready. Any ideas?

Comment: double check the class name on the td you are trying to hide, but make sure no other td is using it. then in your document ready call $('td.class-name-that-is-unique-to-the-column-that-I-am-hiding').hide();

Comment: I'm trying to hide the column with the plus icons, which comes in built with the jqgrid. What is the class name?